# how to install geoviews in python?

Tags: python, pip, geoviews

i was trying to install geoviews using pip but got errors.

```
C:\Users\jainil>pip install geoviews==1.6.2
Collecting geoviews==1.6.2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5d/76/7aa62a5dfdec25ab9f921223bd26507bb603bc5f08a4a7057d3f5e24f42b/geoviews-1.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.0 in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from geoviews==1.6.2) (1.16.4)
Requirement already satisfied: holoviews>=1.11.1 in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from geoviews==1.6.2) (1.12.3)
Requirement already satisfied: bokeh>=1.0.0 in c:\users\jainil\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from geoviews==1.6.2) (1.2.0)
Collecting cartopy>=0.16.0 (from geoviews==1.6.2)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e5/92/fe8838fa8158931906dfc4f16c5c1436b3dd2daf83592645b179581403ad/Cartopy-0.17.0.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\Users\jainil\Anaconda3\python.exe' 'C:\Users\jainil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\jainil\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp25d9ovmd':
  ERROR: setup.py:171: UserWarning: Unable to determine GEOS version. Ensure you have 3.3.3 or later installed, or installation may fail.
    '.'.join(str(v) for v in GEOS_MIN_VERSION), ))
  Proj 4.9.0 must be installed.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'C:\Users\jainil\Anaconda3\python.exe' 'C:\Users\jainil\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\jainil\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp25d9ovmd'" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\jainil\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-sjcurctz\cartopy
```

ok it is solved.

Comment: Why is that ridiculous? What have you tried from reading the message?

Comment: Proj 4.9.0 must be installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by `conda install -c scitools cartopy`